# Embed a data inside JPG file without altering the image in python

Tags: python, image, digital-signature, steganography, piexif

i have 289 bytes of data that i want to embed to a jpg file. Of course without altering the image. Also, i can extract that data from the image and the picture is still original. To proof the originality, the hash value (SHA 256) of the image before and after embedding proses is still the same value.

i've tried using `stegano` library and `piexif`.
this is the code that using `piexif`

```py
exif_dict = piexif.load(pathImg + 'testImage.jpg')
exif_dict["thumbnail"] = signature # Signature is the 289 bytes of data
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(exif_bytes, pathImg + 'testImage.jpg')
```

and i got an error `piexif._exceptions.InvalidImageDataError: Given data isn't JPEG.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by myself and use the code below to insert the value

```py
import piexif

exif_dict = piexif.load('testImageSigned.jpg')
exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Copyright] = hashValue
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(exif_bytes, 'testImageSigned.jpg')
```

And here is the code to extract:

```py
exif_dict = piexif.load('testImageSigned.jpg')
hashValue2 = exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Copyright]
```

[Here](https://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) is the exif tag documentation and there describe the data type.

[And here](https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the `piexif` library documentation.

Hope this can help you